# Specification of panel data

Tags: stata, econometrics, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

I am trying to find out the best specification for my dataset.

I am trying to probe the effectiveness of the special economic zones in Poland in the meaning of growth of the economy in three similar panel data models for explained variables: a) registered unemployment rate b) GDP per capita c) gross fixed capital formation per capita. The data is for NUTS3 sub-regions. The explanatory variables are: 0-1 for presence of the SEZ in sub-region in year $t$ and a few of the economic variables; yearly frequency, dataset is 2004-2012 for 66 sub-regions.

I have tried fixed and random effects. As for now, I have chosen FE, because of significance and theoretically correct signs. But there are some issues that prevent me from taking it for granted:

1. How to test for autocorrelation and cross-correlation?
2. I have no idea how to test the error term's distribution in Stata, and furthermore if it is not normally distributed, should I care about it much?
3. As I understand from the literature, values of the correlation coefficient between explanatory variables and the error term near -1 or 1 are not bad as a matter of fact; in my case, it's nearly -1 as you can see.
4. Is a mixed model appropriate for my dataset?

I attach the outcome for the model explaining unemployment rate.

Code:

```
xtreg  st_bezr sse01 wartosc_sr_trw_per_capita zatr_przem_bud podm_gosp_na_10tys_ludn proc_ludn_wiek_prod ludnosc_na_km2, fe

Fixed-effects (within) regression               Number of obs      =       594
Group variable: id                              Number of groups   =        66

R-sq:  within  = 0.4427                         Obs per group: min =         9
       between = 0.3479                                        avg =       9.0
       overall = 0.2365                                        max =         9

                                                F(6,522)           =     69.10
corr(u_i, Xb)  = -0.9961                        Prob > F           =    0.0000

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                  st_bezr |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
                    sse01 |  -1.406066   .4631984    -3.04   0.003    -2.316028   -.4961045
wartosc_sr_trw_per_capita |  -.0000963   .0000166    -5.79   0.000    -.0001289   -.0000636
           zatr_przem_bud |  -26.11989   4.992198    -5.23   0.000    -35.92716   -16.31263
  podm_gosp_na_10tys_ludn |  -.0201788   .0030788    -6.55   0.000    -.0262273   -.0141304
      proc_ludn_wiek_prod |  -229.1996   16.92631   -13.54   0.000    -262.4516   -195.9475
           ludnosc_na_km2 |   .0790167   .0120865     6.54   0.000     .0552726    .1027609
                    _cons |   161.9786   10.76989    15.04   0.000      140.821    183.1363
--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
                  sigma_u |  53.986519
                  sigma_e |  2.5446248
                      rho |  .99778327   (fraction of variance due to u_i)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
F test that all u_i=0:     F(65, 522) =    27.09             Prob > F = 0.0000
```

Answer (score 12):

For the Stata commands in this answer let me collect your variables in a local: 
`local xlist sse01 wartosc_sr_trw_per_capita zatr_przem_bud podm_gosp_na_10tys_ludn proc_ludn_wiek_prod ludnosc_na_km2` 
So now you can always call all the variables with `xlist'

1) There are two commands that you can use after your fixed effects regression.

- `xttest2` performs a Breusch-Pagan LM test with the null hypothesis of no dependence between the residuals. This is a test for contemporaneous correlation. Not rejecting the null means that the test did not detect any cross-sectional dependence in your residuals.
- `xttest3` performs a modified version of the Wald test for groupwise heteroscedasticity. The null hypothesis is homoscedasticity.

You can install both commands by typing `ssc instal xttest2` and `ssc instal xttest3`. If you detect correlations between your residuals you can correct for this with the robust option:

`xtreg st_bezr 'xlist', fe robust`
 
To test for autocorrelation you can apply a Lagrange Multiplier test via `xtserial`:
`xtserial st_bezr 'xlist'`
The null hypothesis is no serial correlation. To correct for both serial correlation and heteroscedasticity you can use the cluster option with your id variable:
`xtreg st_bezr 'xlist', fe cluster(id)`

2) For the normality test for the residuals: you can obtain the residuals via the predict command `predict res, e` after your fixed effects regression. For visual inspection you can use:

- `kdensity res, normal` (plots the distribution of the residuals and compares it to a normal)
- `pnorm res` (plots a standardized normal probability plot)
- `qnorm res` (plots the quantiles of the residuals against the quantiles of a normal distribution)

With pnorm you can see if there is non-normality in the middle of the distribution and qnorm shows you any non-normality in the tails. A formal test can be obtained by `swilk res`. The null hypothesis is that the residuals are normally distributed. Generally, non-normality is not a too big concern but it matters for inference. You can again correct for this with the robust option.

3) Having `corr(u_i, Xb)  = -0.9961` means that the fixed effects are strongly correlated with your explanatory variables, so you did well by controlling for these fixed effects. A strong correlation of this type usually indicates that pooled OLS or random effects will not be suitable for your purpose because both of these models assume that the correlation between $u_i$ and $X\beta$ is zero.

4) Generally yes but it depends what you want to estimate or how you can treat your data, i.e. whether your variables are random variables or not. [Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34642/difference-between-panel-data-mixed-model) is an excellent explanation for the difference between mixed effects and panel data models by @mpiktas which will surely help you.