# Difference between multilevel modelling and mixed effects models?

Tags: mixed-model, multilevel-analysis

What is the difference between Multilevel/Hierarchical Modelling and Mixed Effects Models?

Wikipedia considers them to be the same, i.e. two different names for the same thing. But I think they are not exactly the same. Could anybody explain the theoretical difference?

Maybe the "Mixed Effects Models" is just one approach to solve Multilevel problems?

Comment: Why would you "think they are not exactly the same"?

Comment: While wikipedia states that [multilevel models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilevel_model) are also called [mixed models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_model), it does make a distinction as they each have their own page.

Answer (score 17):

Section 2.2.2.1 from [lme4 book](http://lme4.r-forge.r-project.org/lMMwR/lrgprt.pdf)

> Because each level of sample occurs with one and only one level of batch we
>   say that sample is nested within batch. Some presentations of mixed-effects
>   models, especially those related to multilevel modeling˜[Rasbash et˜al., 2000]
>   or hierarchical linear models˜[Raudenbush and Bryk, 2002], leave the impression
>   that one can only define random effects with respect to factors that
>   are nested. This is the origin of the terms “multilevel”, referring to multiple,
>   nested levels of variability, and “hierarchical”, also invoking the concept of
>   a hierarchy of levels. To be fair, both those references do describe the use
>   of models with random effects associated with non-nested factors, but such
>   models tend to be treated as a special case.
>
> The blurring of mixed-effects models with the concept of multiple, hierarchical
>   levels of variation results in an unwarranted emphasis on “levels”
>   when defining a model and leads to considerable confusion. It is perfectly legitimate
>   to define models having random effects associated with non-nested
>   factors. The reasons for the emphasis on defining random effects with respect
>   to nested factors only are that such cases do occur frequently in practice and
>   that some of the computational methods for estimating the parameters in
>   the models can only be easily applied to nested factors

Comment: Also related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34642/difference-between-panel-data-mixed-model