# Hierarchical panel data: Fixed effects vs. hierarchical linear models vs. mixed models

Tags: mixed-model, panel-data, multilevel-analysis, fixed-effects-model, cross-section

I have problems about understanding the intuition and differences about when to apply fixed effects, hierarchical linear models (multilevel models) and hierarchical mixed models. I will try to explain my difficulties in understanding with following example I am currently working on.

I would like to analyze the influence of component characteristics to its performance during the product development process. Each component belongs to a subsystem and the subsystem belongs to a product. Thus, I have hierarchical data. The dependent variable is measured on all level. The independent variables are measured on all levels. I have this data for a couple of similar products with the same hierarchical structure resulting in panel data with repeated cross-sections.

Here are some examples of my variables.

Dependent variable:

- Development performance

Independent variables:

- Number of materials
- Weight
- Complexity
- Prior experience
- Novelty
- Subsystem dummy (subsystem level)
- Number of parts (subsystem level)
- Budget (subsystem level)
- Assigned engineers (subsystem level)
- Product dummy (subsystem level)
- Customer segment (product level)
- Market (product level)
- Price (product level)

This is what I understood so far.

**Fixed effects:**

- With the help of fixed effects all time invariant effects will be absorbed, so the omitted variable bias is reduced.
- In my case I would like to use component fixed effects and product fixed effects as I may have left out some variables on the component level and products also differ slightly.
- Due to fixed effects I won’t be able to analyze interaction effects between individual and group level characteristics as group characteristics are absorbed. But this is not a problem as my questions are on the component level.
- Constant factors like the hierarchical dummy variable drop out.

**Hierarchical linear models (multilevel models)**

- Characteristics are analyzed on multiple levels simultaneously
- I could use different types (Random intercepts, random slopes or random intercepts and slopes model)
- Evaluation of interaction effects between individual and group level characteristics is possible.
- But: Here I might get a problem with omitted variable bias

**Hierarchical mixed models**

- Mixed models are characterized as containing both fixed and random effects.
- The fixed effects are analogous to standard regression coefficients and are estimated directly.
- Random effects may take the form of random intercepts or random coefficients.

So here are finally my questions

1. **Fixed effects model: How do I include independent variables from
   higher levels that are not time invariant? 
   Each group data is
   allocated to the individual level??? Is this correct or does it
   violate the independence assumption.**
2. **What is the intuition choosing between fixed effects, hierarchical linear models and mixed models? What conditions should be met?**
3. **What problems (e.g. endogeneity or bias problem) does each model solve?**
4. **Mixed models: What variables should I use as fixed and random effects?**

Comment: Thank you for your comment. i already read that post. Unfortunately, it is not answering my question as it does not address the intuition between choosing the right model.

Comment: You have several questions, so that is possible. Some of the linked threads may be of use to you e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34642/difference-between-panel-data-mixed-model & https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/238214/how-exactly-does-a-random-effects-model-in-econometrics-relate-to-mixed-models